# Accessing django oscar product attributes

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I want to access a product attribute's value. I have defined a product attribute with code `weight` and type `float`. In my views I'm trying to access it as below:

```
def red(request):
    basket = request.basket
    weight_total = 0
    for line in basket.all_lines():
        weight = line.product.attributes.get(code = 'weight')
        weight_total += weight.productattributevalue
```

It doesn't work and gives error:

```
'ProductAttribute' object has no attribute 'productattributevalue'
```

I tried looking into oscar's model but couldn't find the solution. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend copying the Django Oscar shipping/scales.py Scale class [weigh_product() method.](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.0/oscar/apps/shipping/scales.py#L12)

In there, they use the **'value'** property of the *product's* **'attribute_values'** property.

```
try:
    attr_val = product.attribute_values.get( # Using 'attribute_values'
        attribute__code=self.attribute)      # Use your own code of 'weight'
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    if self.default_weight is None:          # You can set a default weight.
        raise ValueError("No attribute %s found for product %s"
                         % (self.attribute, product))
    weight = self.default_weight
else:
    weight = attr_val.value                  # << HERE. using 'value' property
```

Answer (score 3):

To get or set an attribute by code, just do:

```
product.attr.code
```

for example, if the code of your attribute is "weight":

```
product.attr.weight = 125
```

I found that example in the code for `oscar.apps.catalogue.product_attributes` (django-oscar 1.4) and it works both in python and in templates.

Comment: Note that you need to call `product.attr.save()`  to make your assignment persistent.